# how do I extract request parameters and headers of webservices from its url in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, automated-tests

I need to create a SOAP envelop but I only have the URL of the web services. How can I get the headers and parameters to create the SOAP envelop for given URL of the Web services in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You need a WSDL to create the SOAP envelope. One way to get the WSDL is to hit the URL you already have by appending '?wsdl' to the URL. You can also try /ServiceName?wsdl. Once you get the WSDL, you can easily generate SOAP envelope using SoapUI.